# When someone suddenly slows down or stops doing what they started passionately and vigorously

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

When a runner gets exhausted during a competition, they might slow down either:

1. to save energy to keep back going after a short time (intentionally)
2. or just due to the lack of adequate and required energy. (forcefully.)

I want to be a little creative and compare the first (intentional) case to someone who is running out of steam in doing something which they had started passionately and vigorously.

How shall I give them a lift and boost their energy and ask them to hang in there?

As for an intentional act of lowering speed, I am familiar with two idioms "ease up" and "hit the wall". Let's take a look at them:

**Ease up:**

- If you ease up, you start to make less effort.

**Hit the wall:**

- To reach a point when you ate running, exercising, playing sports, etc. where you are so physically tired you feel you cannot continue.

> **Example:** 
> You've already tried a lot. Remember all those tough days. Your whole life depends on the result of this test. You need to pass it. Hang in there. You're just a little way off the finish. [Here, finish" means "achievement of goals".] .........

a. Don't ease up 
b. Don't hit the wall

Would you be so kind as to let me know which choice works here idiomatically?

I am wide open to other and better suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused by the intentional/forceful distinction, and I'm finding it difficult to see how it applies to the case of the person and their "life battle". For example, if a runner intentionally slows down at one point in a race, so as to have energy for later, that doesn't seem at all analogous to a person who has lost their mojo. Overall, it's hard to know exactly what you are asking. Could you clarify? Maybe provide a succinct version of your actual question? (And if that's the intention of the quoted section, beginning with **Question:**, then at least for me it's not doing the job.)

Comment: As a native speaker, neither of these idioms works in your sentence. Maybe try "don't give up"

Comment: Then may I ask you to provide me with any idiomatic idiom/expression in this case @Esther?

Comment: I mentioned "Don't [give up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-up)"(second definition) in my previous comment.

Comment: I have never heard *Don't hit the wall*.  The phrase is strongly associated with running and I don't think it's usage is common enough for it to be considered a universal metaphor.    It is likely to be taken literally in many situations.  Don't ease up.  Don't give up.  Don't slack off.  There are many options better than *hit the wall*.

Comment: @Esther - I don't think *give up* works.  Giving up means to totally quit.  The poster is talking about *easing up*, meaning to not give 100% effort to the task at hand.

Comment: There are definitely a lot of ways to say that in a language like English @EllieK. However, I need an idiom / expression rather than a simple verb. Otherwise I think there are words like "fade", "flatter", "collapse" etc. which more or less can be used in the identical sense as for the running slow-down case. :-)

Comment: @A-friend - *Slack off* works like a charm.  One might *ease up* because they are tired but one who *slacks off* is actively doing less than expected.  Accusing someone of *slacking off*, by the way, is mildly confrontational depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't ease up".

There is no point it telling someone not to hit the wall. Nobody chooses to hit the wall. In fact the only way to avoid "hitting the wall" is to ease up before you hit it! There is nothing intentional about "hitting the wall".  It happens when your body has run out of fuel and you collapse (it not just about being tired during exercise)

But "hitting the wall" is strongly associated with running. I don't think that it can be used metaphorically.

However "ease up" is intentional. People can choose to ease up, or choose not to. So it makes sense to say "Don't ease up".